# Mandar mensajes a telegram usando TLSharp C#

Tags: c#

Hola estoy haciendo un pequeño programa para mandar mensajes a telegram pero el problema esta en que no recibo los mensajes. El código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TLSharp;
using TLSharp.Core;
using System.IO;

namespace telegram
{
    class Program
    {
       const int apiId = 85381;
       const string apiHash = "3e368f6bc7a6b30844b9e88cc940c151";
       const string number = "12067177907";
       const int groupId = 376934156;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new TelegramClient(apiId, apiHash);
            client.ConnectAsync();

            var hash = client.SendCodeRequestAsync(number);
            var code = "55xxx"; // you can change code in debugger
            var user = client.MakeAuthAsync(number, apiHash, code);
            client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = groupId }, "TEST");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí una captura de mis datos para que comprobeis que los datos son correctos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segunda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tercera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo menos tendría que llegarme un mensaje a mi cuenta poniendo `"Test"` pero no recibo nada. En mi caso mi aplicación sería una simple extension.

Referencia: [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp)

Comment: Hola Omar, no conozco esta libreria pero si te interesa puedo mostrarte como hacerlo usando BotFramework. Salu2

Comment: Por otro lado, veo que hay muchos metodos async que estas usando sincronicamente- Te recomiendo leer como usar async await: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hola omar, estoy intentando hacer lo mismo pero no lo puedo lograr, pudiste solucionarlo?

Comment: No, no lo consegui.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta algo en la api token, generalmente la api token de los bots tienen esta expresión: `304017237:AAHpKXZBaw_wOF3H-ryhWl3F3wqIVP_Zqf8`. Intenta colocar la expresión completa ya que veo que sólo tienes `3e368f6bc7a6b30844b9e88cc940c151`. Busca la api token y editala, si no la tienes le puedes preguntar al Bot Father para que te recuerde.

Comment: Graicas por la respuesta. Esta pregunta tiene mas de un año, asi que puede ser que tu respuesta no llegue a ninguna lado, o que en ese momento las key tuvieran ese formato. Tuviste eso en cuenta?

Comment: @gbianchi no me había percatado la fecha. Tienes razón.